# Strategy Pattern in "real life"

Tags: design-patterns, strategy-pattern

I'm trying to transform wikipedia examples of strategy pattern to real life problems, but I'm not sure if my scenario does require such pattern.

say we a have a service that gets updates from several clients, and needs to do some processing and move these updates forward, depends on their size.
i would like to keep the service as simple as possible, and open for future updates formats (from other clients) as well.

I thought I could let the updates themselves decide how to be processes and moved forward, by using this pattern, and let the service be a simple as possible. something like this:

```
public class Service {
    void processUpdate(Update myUpdate) {

        myUpdate.process();
        myUpdate.moveForward();
    }
}
```

Am I wrong ? how (where...) do I assign a strategy to each update ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way to do a bad job with design patterns is to learn a pattern, and then go trying to find places to put it.  I did this a few times when I was first learning, and the results were quite frustrating.

The strategy pattern is a solution for a specific shape of problem.  That problem is " I need to do things that are basically the same, but there are some variations in the middle".  So for now, remember how to do a strategy pattern, and when you see a problem that suggests it, use it.

Answer (score 2):

- What is a Strategy? A strategy is a plan of action designed to achieve a specific goal;
- “Define a family of algorithms, encapsulate each one, and make them interchangeable. Strategy lets the algorithm vary independently from clients that use it.” (Gang of Four);
- Specifies a set of classes, each representing a potential behaviour. Switching between those classes changes the application behaviour. (the Strategy);
- This behaviour can be selected at runtime (using polymorphism) or design time;
- Capture the abstraction in an interface, bury implementation details in derived classes;

[image]

- An alternative to the Strategy is to change the application behaviour by using conditional logic. (BAD);
- Using this pattern makes it easier to add or remove specific behaviour, without having to recode and retest, all or parts of the application;
- Good uses:

  - When we have a set of similar algorithms and its need to switch between them in different parts of the application. With Strategy Pattern is possible to avoid ifs and ease maintenance;
  - When we want to add new methods to superclass that don’t necessarily make sense to every subclass. Instead of using an interface in a traditional way, adding the new method, we use an instance variable that is a subclass of the new Functionality interface. This is known as Composition : Instead of inheriting an ability through inheritance the class is composed with Objects with the right ability;